# Where to add email verification code for android app using parse

Tags: android, email, parse-platform, email-verification

Using Parse for an android app,

I am trying to add email verification concept. When data is entered and submit button is clicked, an email is sent to user. Till that time, `EmailVerified=false`. 
Now with the same credentials, when I am trying to login, it is logging in. 
Without an email verification, I am able to proceed further.

How to solve this problem? 
I want to set `EmailVerified=true` and if `true` then only user can log in with that credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a web service and maintain a field which shows whether the user email verification is done or not...using that you can validate the user and continue him to login...

Comment: Web service? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: We need to write a service and implement the email verification in our backend. Once it is set and when the user tries to login from your app, in the response you can send whether the user is signedup/not and also if signedup then email verified/not. using the response type we can notify the user to do the necessary email verification.

Comment: Okay. Sounds good. Can you please provide me with the link of any such codes so that I can learn from that?

Comment: Alternatively, you might use facebook/twitter to signup process or even you can use the Parse push notification mechanisms...

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact answer to your question  :D

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-app-email-settings/